# Pyqtgraph's ImageView does not emit "time changed" signal

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

Consider this minimal example, where the goal is to display the current "time index" of pyqtgraph's ImageView:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

pg.mkQApp()
view = pg.ImageView()
view.setImage(np.random.normal(size=(100,100,100)))
view.show()

def indexChanged():
    print view.currentIndex

view.sigTimeChanged.connect(indexChanged)
```

As long as the time is changed with the mouse, this works great. Seems like sigTimeChanged is not emitted when the time is changed with the keyboard arrows? Or am I missing something?

Any suggestions to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... I dived into the source code and made a little patch (actually, only reordered the statements):

```
class PatchedImageView(pg.ImageView):
    def timeLineChanged(self):
        (ind, time) = self.timeIndex(self.timeLine)
        self.sigTimeChanged.emit(ind, time)
        if self.ignoreTimeLine:
            return
        self.play(0)
        if ind != self.currentIndex:
            self.currentIndex = ind
            self.updateImage()
```

It seems to work, but I'm not sure I didn't break anything.

Comment: I also took a look at the source code but did not really understand why it is not emitted. Anyway, I integrated your solution into my code and it does not seem to brake anything else I use ImageView for. The only minor difference I noticed is that with your patch, when you hold the keyboard arrows, the time slider moves only one step forward/backward. With the original code order, it keeps moving as long as you keep an arrow pressed. But this works for me, thank's!

Comment: @a.smiet, I fixed the trouble with the time slider (placed self.play(0) after self.ignoreTimeLine flag checking).